# ECL of a Lycanthrope

Tags: dnd-3.5e, lycanthropy

The SRD states that a Lycanthrope has an LA of either +2 or +3, depending on whether it is afflicted or natural. Aside from that, its ECL is affected by several Racial Hit Dice, depending on what animal it is.

I am currently trying to make either a natural Wereboar or Werebear of ECL 8. This SHOULD be possible, since the wereboar has 3 racial hit dice, LA+3, so ECL 6, which room for 2 class lvls.
However, when I fill this in on Heroforge Anew, it says my ECL is 11. Is this a mistake of the program, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible for a natural wereboar to be ECL 7 character (1 humanoid HD*, 3 animal HD, 3 LA) at minimum. So it fits in your ECL 8 requirement.

As for werebear, as printed, you can't create it at given ECL. It's minimum is ECL 9 (1 humanoid HD*, 6 animal HD, 2 LA) for aflicted or ECL 10 (1 humanoid HD*, 6 animal HD, 3 LA) for natural. But given stats are for were[brown]bear, so you may create were[black]bear yourself (not sure if it is possible in heroforge).

---

From numbers alone, you should check if you selected **Effective** Character Level, not Character Level for your werewhatever. It seems programm adds LA over your selected value (8+3=11).

---

* <sup>- This or those HD present regardless of being actual humanoid HD (if your character is lizardfolk werebear, for example) or [being replaced with levels in a class](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/improvingMonsters.htm#humanoidsAndClassLevels) (for something like human or elf).</sup>

Comment: Could you explain how Wereboar is minimum ECL 7? Because as I see it, it'd just have 3LA, 3 Racial HD, which would bring it to ECL 6 with room for 2 class lvls.

Comment: My understanding from the answer is that the natural wearboar is (1 _humanoid_ HD+3 _animal_ (boar) HD + 3LA) = ECL7

Comment: @Arthaban I've editted explanation in. As gaynorvader has allready stated it is caused by minimum of one humanoid HD, which most probably going to be a level in some class.